# Yield in a salt execution module to return status during execution

Tags: python, yield, salt-stack

I am writing a few long running salt execution modules and want to monitor status of execution of these modules. For example, I use the module to copy a huge file, terabytes in size, that might take a few hours. Is it possible to use 'yield' keyword to return progress and then query this progress via salt-api or salt-run? Here is an example:

```
from time import sleep
def longrunningmodule():
   yield 'Progress: 0%'
   sleep(100)
   yield 'Progress: 50%'
   sleep(100)
   yield 'Progress: 100%'
```

Run salt module here:

```
$ salt 'node1' mytest.longrunningmodule --async
Executed command with job ID: 20141015143132465443
```

Can I use this job ID to periodically query the job to check on progress?

Answer (score 2):

I found an indirect way of doing this. While yield doesn't post back results to salt master but salt event bus can be used to post messages, which in turn can be accessed via salt-api. Salt event system is described here http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/event/index.html. More specifically, to fire events from minion to master is mentioned here:

http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/event/index.html#firing-events and http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/event/index.html#firing-events-from-code.

At this moment the second way is buggy and doesn't work. This is described at https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/8849. One of the comment on this same issue has described an alternate way: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/8849#issuecomment-35973524

Answer (score 1):

### Intro

Expanding on [the answer by dOps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27272615/98528), further research led me to build something based on SaltStack *events*, *reactors* and *runners*. For a quick recap of the relevant SaltStack terminology:

- *event* is a 0MQ message that goes from a *minion* to *master*;
- *reactor* is a SaltStack feature which allows to run (special) *.sls* files on the *master*, in reaction (hence the name, *react*or) to events;
- *runner* is a Python script that can be executed on *master* (in similar vein as *modules* can be run on *minions*).

### Steps

In [SaltStack 2014.7](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/2014.7/), I built this like below:

1. Emit events from a module — an example test module my look like below (e.g. `SALT_ROOT/_modules/mymodule.py`). You can view them for initial debugging on master server with [`sudo salt-run state.event`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/2014.7/ref/runners/all/salt.runners.state.html) (IIRC).

   ```
   def test(name=None):
           __salt__['event.send']('my_prefix/tester/mytest', {
                   'foo': 'bar',
                   'baz': True,
           })
           return "test done!"
   ```
2. Edit `/etc/salt/master`and add block like below, then restart *salt-master* (e.g. `sudo restart salt-master`). This will enable registering custom runners:

   ```
   # Add any additional locations to look for master runners:
   runner_dirs: ["MY_RUNNER_PATH"]
   ```
3. Create `MY_RUNNER_PATH/save.py` — a runner which will eventually log the events to a `/tmp/salt-monitor` file. You can test it with `sudo salt-run save.data` (IIRC):

   ```
   import json
   import pprint

   def data(tag_pprint, data_pprint):
       contents = {}
       if not pprint.isreadable(tag_pprint):
           raise Exception(
               'param tag_pprint not readable: {0}'.format(tag_pprint))
       if not pprint.isreadable(data_pprint):
           raise Exception(
               'param data_pprint not readable: {0}'.format(data_pprint))
       contents = {
           'tag': eval(tag_pprint),
           'data': eval(data_pprint),
       }
       with open('/tmp/salt-monitor','ab') as f:
           f.write(json.dumps(contents)+"\n")
   ```
4. Create `/etc/salt/master.d/reactor.conf` file as below (alternatively, this can reportedly be put in the main `/etc/salt/master` config file). This will let us pass the events to the runner we created above. You can somewhat debug this if you set salt-master's log level to 'debug', but there's very little information in logs even then. I think you don't have to reset salt-master here, but not sure. **NOTE**: whitespaces in indentation are important, this is YAML — 2 spaces per indentation level:

   ```
   reactor:
     - 'salt/job/*':
       - MY_REACTOR_PATH/save_event.sls
     - 'my_prefix/*':
       - MY_REACTOR_PATH/save_event.sls
   ```
5. Create `MY_REACTOR_PATH/save_event.sls` as below. Note: I believe you must restart salt-master each subsequent time you change this file after the first time. This can be kinda debugged similarly as point (4) above.

   ```
   event_save:
     runner.save.data:
       - tag_pprint: |
           {{ tag|pprint|replace("\n","\n        ") }}
       - data_pprint: |
           {{ data|pprint|replace("\n","\n        ") }}
   ```

### Logs

Ideally, with log level 'debug' on master, you should have a bunch of lines like below in your logs in `/var/log/salt/master` (they may be intermixed with some other stuff, in the below example some of that was replaced with `...`):

```
2015-12-08 19:01:40,483 [salt.utils.event ][DEBUG   ] Sending event - data = {'_stamp': '2015-12-08T19:01:40.482376', 'pretag': None, 'cmd': '_minion_event', 'tag': 'my_prefix/tester/mytest', 'data': {'foo': 'bar', 'baz': True}, 'id': 'vbox-mc'}
...
2015-12-08 19:01:40,491 [salt.utils.event ][DEBUG   ] Gathering reactors for tag my_prefix/tester/mytest
2015-12-08 19:01:40,491 [salt.utils.event ][DEBUG   ] Compiling reactions for tag my_prefix/tester/mytest
...
2015-12-08 19:01:40,498 [salt.template    ][DEBUG   ] Rendered data from file: /home/akavel/salt/reactors/save_event.sls:
event_save:
  runner.save.data:
    - tag_pprint: |
        u'my_prefix/tester/mytest'
    - data_pprint: |
        {'_stamp': '2015-12-08T19:01:40.482376',
         'cmd': '_minion_event',
         'data': {'baz': True, 'foo': 'bar'},
         'id': 'vbox-mc',
         'pretag': None,
         'tag': 'my_prefix/tester/mytest'}


2015-12-08 19:01:40,501 [salt.loaded.int.render.yaml][DEBUG   ] Results of YAML rendering:
OrderedDict([('event_save', OrderedDict([('runner.save.data', [OrderedDict([('tag_pprint', "u'my_prefix/tester/mytest'\n")]), OrderedDict([('data_pprint', "{'_stamp': '2015-12-08T19:01:40.482376',\n 'cmd': '_minion_event',\n 'data': {'baz': True, 'foo': 'bar'},\n 'id': 'vbox-mc',\n 'pretag': None,\n 'tag': 'my_prefix/tester/mytest'}\n")])])]))])
```